# backbone collection groupby array attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection with objects like:

```
users = {
    'name': 'Johan',
    'groups': [1234, 5678]
}, {
    'name': 'Thomas',
    'groups': [1234]
}, {
    'name': 'Adam',
    'groups': [1234, 5678, 7890]
};
```

I would like to count the `"groups"` and save it in an map like:

```
countArray = [1234 : 3 , 5678 : 2, 7890: 1];
```

so I can access;

```
countArray[1234] -> return 3;
```

or

```
countArray.get('1234') -> return 3;
```

either way

this way I can `_.each` my other collection `"classes"` and look up the number of users in each class.

I was thinking of using functional programming and somehow use `_.groupBy` but I don't see a way to return multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`_.groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) will let you aggregate the objects on a given key or on a value returned by a function, you won't be able to classify multiple objects in the same pass.

You could two `_.each` to build a mapping object :

```
var c = new Backbone.Collection(users);

var res = {};
c.each(function(m) {
    _.each(m.get('groups'), function(g) {
        res[g] = res[g] || 0;
        res[g]++;
    });
});

console.log(res);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/V2qX2/1/ for a demo

Comment: @Johan, may I ask what made you chose for this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `users` being a proper array like this:

```
users = [{
    'name': 'Johan',
    'groups': [1234, 5678]
}, {
    'name': 'Thomas',
    'groups': [1234]
}, {
    'name': 'Adam',
    'groups': [1234, 5678, 7890]
}];
```

Then this will work:

```
var output = {};

for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < users[i].groups.length; j++){
        output[users[i].groups[j]] = (output[users[i].groups[j]] ? output[users[i].groups[j]] + 1 : 1)
    }
}

console.log(output);
// Object {1234: 3, 5678: 2, 7890: 1}
console.log(output[1234]);
// 3
```

Or maybe a little more readable:

```
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < users[i].groups.length; j++){
        var group = users[i].groups[j];
        output[group] = output[group] || 0; // If the current group hasn't been added yet, default value.
        output[group]++;
    }
}
```

The advantage of not using the underscore / backbone libraries for something as simple as this, is that native JS is [**significantly** faster](http://jsperf.com/backbone-underscore-vs-native) than those libraries